# You have an error in your SQL syntax; MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `review` text NOT NULL,
  `image_url` text NOT NULL,
  `promo_url` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO movie (name, desc, review, image_url, promo_url, created_on, modified_on) VALUES ('?p0', '?p1', '?p2', '?p3', '?p4', '?p5', '?p6')
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, review, image_url, promo_url, created_on, modified_on) VALUES ('?p0', '?p1' at line 1
```

I am not able to figure out error source, can anyone please point it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`desc` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Either wrap it in ticks or change it to "description" or any other non-reserved name.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code works. Perhaps the "desc" makes a problem (though you have it in backticks)?

Answer (score 1):

[`DESC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word in MySQL.

You can still use it in the table definition, though.  Just wrap it in backticks:

```
(name, `desc`, ...
```